# React-Router-dom Redirect is not respecting the exact attribute

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

My issue is when trying to redirect the particular url to another url, it by default redirect all the url to the given redirected path. I just want to redirect for a certain path for ex

```
 <Redirect exact from="/" to="/movies"></Redirect>
```

I just want to redirect http://localhost:3000/ t0 http://localhost:3000/movies, which is working fine but now if i visit  http://localhost:3000/xyz it again redirect me to http://localhost:3000/movies

codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-joliot-zbkf9?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example, the router logic? This simply enough code to go on to really help. Are you rendering the `Redirect` within a `Switch`? Can you provide a *running* codesandbox that reproduces the issue?

Comment: No,I am not wrapping the redirect inside the switch,

Answer (score 2):

Instead do :

```
<Route exact path="/">
    <Redirect to="/movies" />
</Route>
```

Comment: with this approach, App is redirecting all the urls to /movies

Answer (score 1):

Redirect [from](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect/from-string) prop

> **Note:** This can only be used to match a location when rendering a
> `<Redirect>` inside of a **`<Switch>`**. See `<Switch children>` for more
> details.

You need to wrap your routes and redirect in a `Switch` in order for the `from` prop to function, and ***not*** specify an earlier *matching* path to that of what you want to redirect from, i.e. "/".

```
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <main className="container">
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/movies" />
          <Route exact path="/test" />
          <Redirect exact from="/" to="/movies" />
        </Switch>
      </main>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-router-dom-redirect-is-not-respecting-the-exact-attribute]

This demo has 3 links, a link to home ("/") which will match the `Redirect`, a link to test ("/test") which will match, and a link to notTest ("/notTest") that won't match any routes. Any other paths also won't be matched by the `Switch`.

Note: a common pattern is to *not* match any route for the redirect and leave it to simply be a "catch-all" path that can redirect to a known/handled path in your app/router.